# Symfony 3.4.6 - 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Index column size too large

Tags: mariadb, symfony-3.4, php-7.1

Inplanting my site on my server, i have this error:

`ERROR 1709 (HY000) at line 278: Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.`

Server type:

> nginx/1.11.10
>
> Versión del cliente de base de datos: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
>
> extensión PHP: mysqliDocumentación curlDocumentación mbstringDocumentación
>
> Versión de PHP: 7.1.14

Database:

> Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket
>
> Tipo de servidor: MariaDB
>
> Conexión del servidor: No se está utilizando SSL Documentación
>
> Versión del servidor: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 - Debian 9.6
>
> Versión del protocolo: 10

On my `config.yml` (from this doc https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) put `server_version` as `10.1.37-mariadb` but the problem not dissapear.

Any idea?

Comment: [_5 workarounds_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes)

Answer (score 2):

To fix the column size issue, you have to change the database configuration.
Make sure you edit the existing settings or add them if they are not set, to;

```
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
innodb-file-format=Barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=ON
innodb-large-prefix=1
```

Ofcourse you also need to restart the database instance to complete the configuration. It's always wise to backup your databases before applying the changes and restart, just in case something goes wrong.

Finally you have to locate the doctrine settings in either your `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` or `app/config/config.yml` and change them to the following;

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.1.37'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
            row_format: DYNAMIC
```

After these changes, clear the symfony cache and recreate the database;

```
console doctrine:database:drop
console cache:clear
console doctrine:database:create
```

Done! All should be working now!

You can read-up on the issue here;

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6398
- https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database

Comment: Finally I migrated to a higher version of MaraDB and everything works perfectly, but in the future, I will test your solution.

Thank you